# How to automatically set app as default for a particular accessory?

Tags: android, usb, android-open-accessory

I'm working on a custom accessory for Android using the Android Open Accessory API. When I first install the app and connect the accessory, it prompts me with "Open [My app] when this USB accessory is connected?", with an option to set it as a default app. When I set it as default, it then opens automatically on subsequent connections.

What I am wondering is whether it is possible for my app to auto-register itself as default in order to cut out the extra step for new users.